# Find lowest value and update other table with that value

Tags: sql, performance, sql-update

I have 2 tables in SQL : Event and Swimstyle
The Event table has a value SwimstyleId which refers to Swimstyle.id
The Swimstyle table has 3 values : distance, relaycount and strokeid

Normally there would be somewhere between 30 and 50 rows in the table Swimstyle, which would hold all possible values (these are swimming distances like 50 (distance), 1 (relaycount), FREE (strokeid)).
However, due to a programming mistake the lookup for existing values didn't work and the importer of new results created a new swimstyle entry for each event added...
My Swimstyle table now consists of almost 200k rows, which ofcourse is performance wise not the best idea ;)

To fix this i want to go through all Events, get the swimstyle values that are attached, lookup the first existing row in Swimstyle that has the same distance, relaycount and strokeid values and update the Event.SwimstyleId with that value.

When this is all done i can delete all orphaned Swimstyle rows, leaving a table with only 30-50 rows.

I have been trying to make a query that does this, but not getting anywhere. Anyone to point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Does the swimstyle table have a primary key field in addition to the 3 you mentioned?

Comment: can you show sample records with your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 statements should fix the problem, if I've read it right. N.B. I haven't been able to try this out anywhere, and I've made a few assumptions about the table structure.

```
UPDATE event e
set swimstyle_id = (SELECT MIN(s_min.id)
                    FROM   swimstyle s_min,swimstyle s_cur
                    WHERE  s_min.distance   = s_cur.distance
                    AND    s_min.relaycount = s_cur.relaycount
                    AND    s_min.strokeid   = s_cur.strokeid
                    AND    s_cur.id         = e.swimstyle_id);

DELETE FROM swimstyle s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM   event e
                  WHERE  e.swimstyle_id = s.id);
```